# Perl - simple if statement wont work

Tags: perl, stdin

I'm trying to write a loop that will determine whether the user input matches the string $rev. No matter what I type in for $seq, it returns that it is NOT a match, even if it actually is. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
$seq = <>;
$rev = "string";
if ($seq eq $rev){
    printf("The two strings match.\n");
}
else {
    printf("The two strings do NOT match.\n");
}
```

Comment: You always type a newline, but don't remove it. `chomp`.

Comment: If you don't need the extra functionality of `printf`, you should use `print` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input to remove the newline character:

```
$seq = <>;
chomp $seq;
$rev = "string";
if ($seq eq $rev){
    print "The two strings match.\n";
}
else {
    print "The two strings do NOT match.\n";
}
```

Also, use `print` instead of `printf` since you are not specifying a format.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your code

```
$seq = <>;
```

to

```
chomp($seq = <>);
```